# jQuery/Ajax - Click to reveal

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to basically create a link which says:

```
<a href="#" id="reveal" alt="928">Click here to show contact information</a>
```

Upon clicking it, it will ping a script via an ajax request, the ajax request will look up the user table where the ID is what is contained in the alt tag, it will return a certain field from the database and then the div will change from this link, to a contact number.

I'm sure some of you have seen this done before, for example:

Click to see persons phone number

They click it, and it changes to their phone number.

How would I go about doing this? I want to do it using ajax instead of having the phone number in the source code, because that really defeats the purpose of them having to click to reveal if bots can get it from the source code.

Thanks :)

Comment: Pretty sure it wouldn't be too difficult for bots to hit your ajax urls to retrieve the data.

Comment: There will always be a way for bots to get information, but if you can make it harder for them to get it, the bots will have to be coded specifically for such site. For example an AJAX post request returning "&#048;&#057;&#056;&#055;&#032;&#048;&#050;&#057;&#032;&#057;&#050;&#056;" would be a lot harder than having the phone number in the source code ready for it to grab.

Answer (score 1):

Somethign along the lines of

```
$("#reveal").click(function(){

$.get('getphoneNumber.php',{id:$(this).attr('alt')}, function(data) {

    $('#reveal').html(data);

   });
});
```

with a php script called getphoneNumber.php that accepts a get parameter of id

Comment: Nope, the `this` won't refer to the `#reveal` element in the `get`'s callback. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" id="reveal" alt="928">Click here to show contact information</a>
<div id="myHiddenDiv"></div>

$("#reveal").click(function(){
   $.get("test.php", { id: $(this).attr("alt") },
     function(data){
         $("#myHiddenDiv").html(data);
         $("#myHiddenDiv").show();
     });
});
```

This example works assuming you've only got one of these "plugins" on your site, if you'll have multiple, use this:

```
<a href="#" class="reveal" alt="928">Click here to show contact information</a>
<div class="myHiddenDiv"></div>

$(".reveal").click(function(){
   var divSelector = $(this).next("div");
   $.get("test.php", { id: $(this).attr("alt") },
     function(data){
         divSelector.html(data);
         divSelector.show();
     });
});
```

Comment: I don't think the `this` inside the `get` callback refers to the `.reveal` element anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$('#reveal').click(function () {
    var th = $(this);
    $.get('/get-the-phone-number', { id: th.attr('alt') }, function (response) {
        th.text(response);
    });
});
```

Also, I'd recommend you put the `id` number inside a `data-contact-id` attribute and access it via `th.data('contact-id')` instead of using the `alt` attribute. Ignore me if you have other reasons to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#reveal").live('click',function(event) {
var link = $(this).attr('alt');
var dataString = 'alt=' + link ;

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "url",
            cache:false,
            data: dataString,

            success: function(data){

                this.href = this.href.replace(data);




            }

        });

}
```